# Emit particles as a cone shaped beam

Tags: particles, emission

I am trying to create a beam of particles shaped like a cone.  When I do this from the face of a cube, for example, I get a beam that is normal to that face but I don't know how to make that beam diverge as it travels farther away, sort of like the beam from a flashlight. Thank you!

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Not yet. Still using a cylindrical beam normal to the emitting face. Do you know how to make the beam diverge? Thanks!

Comment: I'll get it going and post up an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Blend file below)

[image]

The emitter is just a section of a standard UV sphere.
Particles are launched evenly from it's faces so the pattern is radial.

[image]

The emitter is placed inside 2 solidified but invisible cones that are setup as "collision objects" (physics) so they effectively focus/deflect particles.

[image]

If any escape in your version, try increasing the "Particles --> Physics --> Subframe" slider, but be mindful that each increment will labour your computer further.

In this example, (Blender Vers 2.77) the default particle settings were used throughout, apart from the emitter and draw size. (in Display tab)

With this arrangement, force fields or other coersions aren't necessary.  The number and size of the particles plus the renderer used will determine how dense it looks.

-=============-

The circular 'Nav-handle' is a common parent that holds it all together for when the emitter is to be animated,

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you!  A couple of questions, though. Why did you use two cones instead of one? And how and why did you create the Nav-handle to parent? I am using Blender 2.83.

Comment: One cone alone couldn't contain the odd determined particle and I was reluctant to increase the subframes, so a 2nd one was wrapped around the 1st.

Comment: The Nav-handle is just an empty - a common parent to glue the emitter and cones together so it can be rotated or dragged around at will.  It's not necessary for the emission.  I find when other factors come into things later, such as physics or constraints, it's better to apply them to a parent rather than the model(s) themselves when they're busy doing other things.

Comment: As for how -, select the emitter, use SH-S to set the cursor to that location, then ADD an Empty (circle or whatever).  Parent whatever's not parented to something else, to the empty.  Drag the assembly around by the empty, not the models.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!