# Is it possible to delete meshes that have baked physics?

Tags: physics, baking, rigid-body-simulation, cache

It took 17 hours to bake 50k small objects all colliding in a container.  There are times when some of those objects escape the container and I’d like to just delete those meshes entirely.  Trouble is when I select them and x>delete nothing happens.

I’m trying to bake to keyframes because I know I can delete them once that’s complete- but it’s been two hours now and it’s still churning away (and/or it’s frozen).  Is there a way to keep the bake and delete the few escaped rigid body objects without having to wait for the keyframes or going through another bake with higher step count?

Comment: maybe try in the header menu > Object > Rigid Body > Bake To Keyframes? (but keep a copy of the original somewhere)

Comment: Honestly talking with ya , never encountered that problem but , Honestly talking with ya , never spent that much time on baking

Comment: Moonboots, that’s what I was in the middle of doing but was taking way too long.  Looking for a way besides that one, unfortunately.

Comment: Mask the escapees out visually perhaps?  In case you need to redo, I wonder if this might help?  Note two cone guides are used because some can escape the first... -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188262/emit-particles-as-a-cone-shaped-beam/190249#190249